# HTTP global PHP variables

Tags: php, global

Is there a way to get a reference to the global arrays that contain HTTP request data like get, post, cookie, etc. ? For example:

```
$varName = getRequestReference()['varName'];
```

where getRequestReference() would return &$_GET, &$_POST...depending on the type of request that the user used to submit data in the script.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're after $_REQUEST variable?

[Request variable docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_REQUEST` to either grab the `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_COOKIE` values

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) for more details.

You could also create a custom function that either grabs `$_POST` or `$_GET`, depending which has the requested key:

```
function getRequest($key)
{
    if(!empty($_GET[$key]))
    {
        return $_GET[$name];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST[$key]))
    {
        return $_POST[$name];
    }

    return null;
}

$varValue = getRequest('varName');
```

This function will return the updated values (when you modify one of these global variables at run-time)

Comment: I know about $_REQUEST, however I wanted a reference because if the contents of the get or post (or whatever the request was) are modified at runtime the $_REQUEST will not reflect that change as opposed to a reference.

Comment: I have updated my answer, with a solution to keep using `$_GET` and `$_POST`, so it will provide updated values (which you seem planning to do). Personally, I would not update these global variables, as it might provide confusion later (eg when you forgot you updated them and expected a different value)

Comment: Thanks for that..though it would be useful if php could offer a reference to the global array depending on the type of request.